# How to display an image using tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to display an image to a tkinter window but every method i tried comes up with the error _tkinter.TclError: unexpected end of file

```
#my method

from tkinter import *

mainWindow = Tk()

labelPicture = Label(mainWindow)
labelPicture.img = PhotoImage(file = "file.png")
labelPicture.config(image = labelPicture.img)
labelPicture.place(in_ = mainWindow, x = 0, y = 0)
```

Comment: Works fine with Python 3.6.5 under windows10. Are you sure the image is ok?

Comment: @figbeam i am using linux, is this why it doesn't work for me ?

Comment: Probably not. When image formats change sometimes libraries can't parse the latest format. I'd try a few different PNG images and a few GIF images as well.

Comment: when I add `mainWindow.mainloop()` then it works on Linux too. Problem can file uncorrect file.

Comment: if I use incomplete file .png (truncated to 1kb with command `truncate -s1000 file.png`) then I get the same error `_tkinter.TclError: unexpected end of file`